# DevExpress Winforms XtraGrid - how to know when grid is done with processing data source change

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

How can I figure out when XtraGrid is done with processing data source change?

I am using IBindingList as data source for grid.
When IBindingList is invoking ListChanged event I want to stop more updates from being sent to grid until it is done with current grid. I tried waiting for "Paint" event on grid, but it does not always happen - sometime update is for row that is off screen, and then Paint is not triggered.

Comment: ListChanged is usually raised when changes were already done. Do you have ListChanged raised several times in a row?

Comment: Please show some code of how you are updating the list? is it done async?

Comment: I have high-frequency stream of changes to my IBindingList, but I invoke ListChanged events only when UI ask for it. UI is asking for update only after grid is done with previous update.

Comment: In fact I have found solution - using grid's Invalidate event. If data source change causes change to screen, than Invalidate is called. otherwise there is no repaint required and I am free to do another data source update.